# How to change a variable already displayed?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, sql-update

I want to update two line of a html table after writing in DataBase without a refresh. Now everything is working fine, unless this thing and i have to refresh the page to see the modified values in the table.

Here is my pages:

first.php

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT S.ID_student, C.name, D.h-theory, D.h-practice FROM students as S, students_details as D WHERE D.ID_student=C.ID_student AND S.ID_student=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);  
echo'</br></br>

<table class="my-tabel">
    <tr><td>Student name</td><td>'.$row['name'].'</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hours of practice/td><td>'.$row['h-theory'].'</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hours of theory</td><td>'.$row['h-practice'].'</td></tr>
</table>';

 ?>

 <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="post">
    <label>Hours of practice:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp </label> </td> <td><input type="text" id="practice" class="text" name="h_practice"/>
    <label>Hours of theory:</label> </td> <td> <input type="text" id="theory" class="text" name="h_theory"/>
    <input type="submit" class="send-h" value="Submit">
 </form>

 <script>
    $('.send-h').click(function(){
        $('.send-h').fadeOut();
        var practice = false;
        var theory = false;
        practice = $('#practice').val();
        theory = $('#theory').val();
        var id = <?php echo json_encode($id) ?>;
        jQuery.get('add.php?practice='+practice+'&theory='+theory+'&id='+id, function(data,self){
        });
    });

 </script>
```

add.php

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$id=$_GET['id'];
$practice=$_GET['practice'];
$theory=$_GET['theory'];
$sql="UPDATE `student_details` SET `ore_practice`='$practice', `ore_theory`='$theory' WHERE ID_student='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
 ?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: use AJAX to post the data being sent do the database.

Comment: Well...apparently a couple of people believe they can decipher what you mean, since they posted answers, but I can't even parse "Now everything is working fine, unless this thing and i have to refresh the page to see the modified values in the table", let alone figure out what you mean by that. Please restate the question more clearly, and I'll nominate it for reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all :

$id = $_GET['id'];
//mysql inject danger

```
$query =" ... HERE D.ID_student=C.ID_student AND S.ID_student=$id";
```

use mysql_real_escape_string for strings
$id is numeric so at least do

$query =" ... HERE D.ID_student=C.ID_student AND S.ID_student=".($id+0);

To add the html line, you will need to use ajax in a function that receives the form data.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

One not so elegant solution would be that add.php would output the new html needed in the table:

```
$('.send-h').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'add.php?practice='+practice+'&theory='+theory+'&id='+id,
  }).done(function(html_response) {
    $( "#YOUR_LIST_ID" ).append(html_response);
  });
}
```

Bear in mind that the query can fail for various reasons.
This is why you shouldn't blindly add the data you submited.
add.php must also output a "success" flag.

so add.php can output

```
echo json_encode(array('success'=>1, 'html'=> $generated_html)); //if all ok
```

or

```
echo json_encode(array('success'=>0, 'html'=> '')); //if all not ok
```

and in the .done(function(response)) you do

```
var obj = jQUery.parseJSON(response);
if (obj.success == 1) {
  $( "#YOUR_LIST_ID" ).append(obj.html);
}else{
  alert('dberror');
}
```

Also you may want to use Datatables ( http://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html )
if you are planning to use this kind of stuff often.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to do the following

```
 <script>
    $('.send-h').click(function(){
        $('.send-h').fadeOut();
        var practice = false;
        var theory = false;
        practice = $('#practice').val();
        theory = $('#theory').val();
        var id = <?php echo json_encode($id) ?>;
        jQuery.get('add.php?practice='+practice+'&theory='+theory+'&id='+id, function(data,self){

            console.log(data); // Shows the returned data in the console
            $('#my_id').html(data); // Shows the returned data in an element with the id `my_id`

        });
    });

 </script>
```

You can `echo` in `add.php` with the response so something like `echo $result;` would be your last line in the `add.php` file and that should be in the `data` variable of your function.

And then you can use `$(some_selector).html(data)` to show the returned content in some selector or you can also use `append`, `$(some_selector).append(data)`